# Strange alignment issue with form

Tags: html, css

I have a contact form at the bottom of my web page.

Whenever I click on any of the fields of the forms, the alignment goes all crazy. It doesn't happen on my phone, it doesn't happen when I run the site locally (i.e. on my PC directly from the source code on my hard drive. Offline).

Link to my web page: [thisisit.coolpage.biz](http://thisisit.coolpage.biz)

CSS used for center alignment(found on an online tutorial):

```
form {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:459px;
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
}

textarea {
    width:439px;
    height:27px;
    background:#efefef;
    border:1px solid #dedede;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:3px;
    font-size:0.9em;
    color:#3a3a3a;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

P.S- Ignore the content on the page please :P

Comment: make sure content is not cached. try Ctrl+F5 and check page again

Comment: seems ok to me?

Comment: You are using the same `id` twice on one page. use `class` or remove one. ` <p id="p1">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple `id` with the same name on one `HTML` page can cause problems.

Change your rule in your css to a class:

change:

```
#p1{
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
}
```

to:

```
.p1{
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
}
```

then on your PAGE change `<p id="p1">` to `<p class="p1">`. I would try to stay away from multiple IDs on elements like `<h1>` and `<p>`. Otherwise your centering looks okay to me.

Comment: I made the changes but nothing happened.

Comment: @YaddyVirus - can you show me the display error you are getting? I do not see what you are describing in the code. You should though never use the same ID for an element in one page.

Comment: I am not using the same ID for 2 elements... As you suggested, I changed the id `p1` to `class="p1"` and did the required changes in the CSS as well. The problem still exists. The input bars are in the center initially, as soon as I click on them to enter text, they get arranged side by side. I also made a new website with the same form and that website is also facing the same issue. It does NOT happen on mobile devices or when ran locally on my computer. Go to my website and try entering data in that form you'll see for yourself

Comment: I am sorry I just tried this on 3 different browsers and I could not repeat the problem. What would help is if you gave a screenshot of the problem and the browser that you use.

Comment: You were right. I tried my page on Firefox and it worked correctly. The problem is only on chrome. Since I use chrome only, I never tested it on any other browser. Thanks for the help!
P.S How to fix the issue on chrome? Clear cache maybe?